# R terra package error in reading netcdf: No UNIDATA NC_GLOBAL:Conventions attribute

Tags: r, gdal, terra

I am trying to read the below netcdf using `terra` package. The netcdf file contains data for 3 years. When I load the data, it gives me below warning which I never had before.

```
gdp <- terra::rast(file.path(dir_ls$base, 'v3.nc'))

Warning message:
In new_CppObject_xp(fields$.module, fields$.pointer, ...) :
   GDAL Message 1: No UNIDATA NC_GLOBAL:Conventions attribute
```

If I check the projection, it shows me NA

```
crs(gdp)
```

Even I try to project the data, the projection is still NA

```
 gdp <- terra::project(gdp, "epsg:4326")
 crs(gdp)
 NA
```

EDIT

```
 terra::gdal(lib="")
 gdal    proj    geos 
"2.2.3" "4.9.3" "3.7.1
```

The gdp file looks like

```
class       : SpatRaster 
dimensions  : 21600, 43200, 3  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
resolution  : 0.008333333, 0.008333333  (x, y)
extent      : -180, 180, -90, 90  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : lon/lat WGS 84 (EPSG:4326) 
source      : GDP_PPP_30arcsec_v3.nc 
varname     : GDP_PPP (Gross Domestic Production (GDP) (PPP)) 
names       :                             GDP_PPP_1,                             GDP_PPP_2,                             GDP_PPP_3 
unit        : constant 2011 international US dollar, constant 2011 
international US dollar, constant 2011 international US dollar
```

My session info is here:

```
R version 4.0.5 (2021-03-31)
    Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
    Running under: Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS
    
    Matrix products: default
    BLAS:   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/blas/libblas.so.3.7.1
    LAPACK: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/lapack/liblapack.so.3.7.1
    
    locale:
    [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C               LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8       
    [4] LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8     LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8   
    [7] LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                  LC_ADDRESS=C              
    [10] LC_TELEPHONE=C             LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       
    
    attached base packages:
    [1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     
    
    other attached packages:
    [1] rgdal_1.5-32      rgeos_0.5-9       raster_3.4-10     sp_1.4-5          geodata_0.4-9    
    [6] sf_0.9-8          terra_1.6-7       forcats_0.5.1     stringr_1.4.0     dplyr_1.0.6      
    [11] purrr_0.3.4       readr_1.4.0       tidyr_1.1.3       tibble_3.1.1      ggplot2_3.3.3    
    [16] tidyverse_1.3.1   data.table_1.14.0
    
    loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
    [1] tinytex_0.31       tidyselect_1.1.1   xfun_0.22          lattice_0.20-44   
    [5] haven_2.4.1        colorspace_2.0-1   vctrs_0.3.8        generics_0.1.0    
    [9] utf8_1.2.1         rlang_0.4.11       e1071_1.7-6        pillar_1.6.0      
    [13] glue_1.4.2         withr_2.4.2        DBI_1.1.1          dbplyr_2.1.1      
    [17] modelr_0.1.8       readxl_1.3.1       lifecycle_1.0.0    munsell_0.5.0     
    [21] gtable_0.3.0       cellranger_1.1.0   rvest_1.0.0        codetools_0.2-18  
    [25] class_7.3-19       fansi_0.4.2        broom_0.7.6        Rcpp_1.0.6        
    [29] KernSmooth_2.23-20 scales_1.1.1       backports_1.2.1    classInt_0.4-3    
    [33] jsonlite_1.7.2     fs_1.5.0           hms_1.0.0          stringi_1.6.1     
    [37] grid_4.0.5         cli_2.5.0          tools_4.0.5        magrittr_2.0.1    
    [41] proxy_0.4-25       crayon_1.4.1       pkgconfig_2.0.3    ellipsis_0.3.2    
    [45] xml2_1.3.2         reprex_2.0.0       lubridate_1.7.10   assertthat_0.2.1  
    [49] httr_1.4.2         rstudioapi_0.13    R6_2.5.0           units_0.7-1       
    [53] compiler_4.0.5
```

Comment: Which `gdal` do you have when you `library(sf)`?

Comment: @Chris or see `terra::gdal(lib="")`

Comment: @89_Simple, can you please `show(gdp)`

Comment: I have edited the question to provide the details you asked for

Comment: Not directly applicable to your current problem, but have you considered updating your spatial stack, `gdal`, `proj` and `geos`?, as certain of these issues, `No UNIDATA..` seems to have issues in gdal-2, though don't know if that wasn't fixed by 2.2.3...

Comment: Okay thanks for the suggestion. In another laptop of mine, the version of these packages are    `gdal    proj    geos "3.2.1" "7.2.1" "3.9.1"` and I don't have any problem. So maybe it is down to the older packages. I will give it a go

Comment: If you provide link to `v3.nc`, I can try against gdal-3.5.1, proj-9.0.1, geos-3.11.0...

Comment: The data is downloaded from a natural paper and is located here 
https://datadryad.org/stash/dataset/doi:10.5061/dryad.dk1j0

Comment: `terra::rast("GDP_PPP_30arcsec_v3.nc")` succeeds without any warnings using terra 1.6-7 and gdal 3.4.3, proj 7.2.1, geos 3.9.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you show, `gdp` clearly has a defined coordinate reference system:

```
coord. ref. : lon/lat WGS 84 (EPSG:4326)
```

and projecting it to that same crs again makes no sense.

I do not think that terra would ever report a crs as `NA`. Since you are not showing your actual code and results, it is hard to say what goes wrong. But one red flag is that you have many packages loaded. If you start with a clean session (without any packages loaded) you should be able to do

```
library(terra)
r <- rast("filename")
crs(r)
```

And get a better result. Perhaps you load another package that hides the terra::crs method? In that case, you could do

```
terra::crs(r)
```

Like this:

```
library(terra)
r <- rast("GDP_per_capita_PPP_1990_2015_v2.nc")
r
#class       : SpatRaster 
#dimensions  : 2160, 4320, 26  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
#resolution  : 0.08333333, 0.08333334  (x, y)
#extent      : -180, 180, -90, 90  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#coord. ref. : lon/lat WGS 84 
#source      : GDP_per_capita_PPP_1990_2015_v2.nc 
#varname     : GDP_per_capita_PPP (Gross Domestic Production (GDP) per capita (PPP)) 
#names       :                           GDP_p~PPP_1,                           GDP_p~PPP_2,                           GDP_p~PPP_3,                           GDP_p~PPP_4,                           GDP_p~PPP_5,                           GDP_p~PPP_6, ... 
#unit        : constant 2011 international US dollar, constant 2011 international US dollar, constant 2011 international US dollar, constant 2011 international US dollar, constant 2011 international US dollar, constant 2011 international US dollar, ... 

crs(r, proj=T)
#[1] "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs"
```

None of this has to do with the warning you are getting (I think you can ignore that warning).